# How to continue animation in a page that is disposed in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-navigation, flutter-timer

Basically, I have a bunch of ListTiles on my home page which represents some timers. When I press a ListTile it navigator goes to another page with an option to set a timer and a cool clock animation. Now when I go back to the home page the animation and that complete page get disposed. but I want the timer to continue even if we close the page. Can I get a good suggestion to implement this idea?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you cancelling the timer in the dispose method of its page? My understanding is that timers continue to run until u cancel them.

Comment: I'm not using Timers. I mean I  wasn't aware of such a class exists. Let me try the same using timers.

Comment: Ok, if you don't come right maybe share minimal snippets of your code otherwise everyone is guessing.

Comment: I did it with timers. It worked.   Thanks

Comment: Great, glad I helped albeit indirectly 

Answer (score 1):

In your stateful widget, include a mixin like this!

```
class _ClassNameState extends State<ClassName> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<Upload> {
//code
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how  AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin works. I tried including it as you said, but no luck.